# PostgreSQL ORDER BY issue - natural sort

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I've got a Postgres `ORDER BY` issue with the following table:

```
em_code  name
EM001    AAA
EM999    BBB
EM1000   CCC
```

To insert a new record to the table,

1. I select the last record with `SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY em_code DESC`
2. Strip alphabets from em_code usiging reg exp and store in `ec_alpha`
3. Cast the remating part to integer `ec_num`
4. Increment by one `ec_num++`
5. Pad with sufficient zeors and prefix `ec_alpha` again

When `em_code` reaches EM1000, the above algorithm fails.

First step will return EM999 instead EM1000 and it will again generate EM1000 as new `em_code`, breaking the unique key constraint.

Any idea how to select EM1000?

Comment: Why don't you just use sequence?

Comment: Why not use a sequence? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: Oh dear a classic. Rule one for computerising paper systems, intelligent numbers are dumb. put em in one column, an int in the other sort by both. Build it back into one id for the dumb humans when you need to.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter Thanks for those edits

Comment: Note that the approach you describe will fail miserably if more than one transaction at a time is `INSERT`ing, unless you `LOCK TABLE` first. Regarding the sort, you might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965463/humanized-or-natural-number-sorting-of-mixed-word-and-number-strings) quite informative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that the string sorts alphabetically (instead of numerically like you would want it) and `1` sorts before `9`.
You could solve it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
ORDER  BY substring(em_code, 3)::int DESC;
```

It would be more efficient to drop the redundant 'EM' from your `em_code` - if you can - and save an integer number to begin with.

#### Answer to question in comment

To strip any and all non-digits from a string:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(em_code, E'\\D','','g')
FROM   employees;
```

`\D` is the regular expression [class-shorthand](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) for "non-digits".
`'g'` as 4th parameter is the "globally" switch to apply the replacement to every occurrence in the string, not just the first.

After replacing every non-digit with the empty string, only digits remain.

Comment: The `EM` could be stored in another column for example and both columns could be declared as a key for the table. That would also simplify the inserting new row stuff.

Comment: Is there any way to strip any non digits instead of using `substring` ?

Comment: @Mithun: There is. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Replacing non-digits with 0 (`regexp_replace(…, E'\\D+','0','g')::int`) allows integer conversion even for strings not containing digits

Answer (score 32):

Since Postgres 9.6, it is possible to specify a collation which will sort columns with numbers naturally.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/collation.html

```sql
-- First create a collation with numeric sorting
CREATE COLLATION numeric (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colNumeric=yes');

-- Alter table to use the collation
ALTER TABLE "employees" ALTER COLUMN "em_code" type TEXT COLLATE numeric;
```

Now just query as you would otherwise.

`SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY em_code`

On my data, I get results in this order (note that it also sorts foreign numerals):

| Value |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0001 |
| 001 |
| 1 |
| 06 |
| 6 |
| 13 |
| ۱۳ |
| 14 |

Comment: This should definitely get more upvotes. Arguably the cleanest and most idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 20):

One approach you can take is to create a `naturalsort` function for this. Here's an example, written by Postgres legend [RhodiumToad](https://github.com/RhodiumToad).

```
create or replace function naturalsort(text)
    returns bytea language sql immutable strict as $f$
    select string_agg(convert_to(coalesce(r[2], length(length(r[1])::text) || length(r[1])::text || r[1]), 'SQL_ASCII'),'\x00')
    from regexp_matches($1, '0*([0-9]+)|([^0-9]+)', 'g') r;
$f$;
```

Source: http://www.rhodiumtoad.org.uk/junk/naturalsort.sql

To use it simply call the function in your order by:

```
SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY naturalsort(em_code) DESC
```

Comment: Any idea what's the minimum version of PostgreSQL where this will work?

Answer (score 8):

This always comes up in questions and in my own development and I finally tired of tricky ways of doing this. I finally broke down and implemented it as a PostgreSQL extension:

https://github.com/Bjond/pg_natural_sort_order

It's free to use, MIT license.

Basically it just normalizes the numerics (zero pre-pending numerics) within strings such that you can create an index column for full-speed sorting au naturel. The readme explains.

The advantage is you can have a trigger do the work and not your application code. It will be calculated at machine-speed on the PostgreSQL server and migrations adding columns become simple and fast.

Answer (score 5):

you can use just this line
"ORDER BY length(substring(em_code FROM '[0-9]+')), em_code"

Answer (score 2):

I wrote about this in detail in this related question:

[Humanized or natural number sorting of mixed word-and-number strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965463/humanized-or-natural-number-sorting-of-mixed-word-and-number-strings)

(I'm posting this answer as a useful cross-reference only, so it's community wiki).

Answer (score 2):

I came up with something slightly different.

The basic idea is to create an array of tuples `(integer, string)` and then order by these.  The magic number 2147483647 is int32_max, used so that strings are sorted after numbers.

```
  ORDER BY ARRAY(
    SELECT ROW(
      CAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(match[1], ''), '2147483647') AS INTEGER),
      match[2]
    )
    FROM REGEXP_MATCHES(col_to_sort_by, '(\d*)|(\D*)', 'g')
    AS match
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is a combination of various ideas presented in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12965463/19163), as well as some ideas from the [classic solution](http://www.rhodiumtoad.org.uk/junk/naturalsort.sql):

```
create function natsort(s text) returns text immutable language sql as $$
  select string_agg(r[1] || E'\x01' || lpad(r[2], 20, '0'), '')
  from regexp_matches(s, '(\D*)(\d*)', 'g') r;
$$;
```

The design goals of this function were simplicity and pure string operations (no custom types and no arrays), so it can easily be used as a drop-in solution, and is trivial to be indexed over.

*Note:* If you expect numbers with more than `20` digits, you'll have to replace the hard-coded maximum length `20` in the function with a suitable larger length. Note that this will directly affect the length of the resulting strings, so don't make that value larger than needed.