# Query failed: collation "numerickn" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, natural-sort

I have a column (vendor_name) in Postgresql (AWS RDS) table which can contain alphanumeric values. I would like to do a natural sort on this column.

The sample data in the table is as follows

```
delta 20221120
delta 20220109
costco delivery 564
costco delivery 561
united 01672519702943
Uber
```

I have created a colllate in the db as below.

```
CREATE COLLATION IF NOT EXISTS numerickn (provider = icu, locale = 'en-u-kn-true')
```

If anyone sorts on the vendor name column in the UI grid, I am adding the following clause dynamically in my query.

```
ORDER BY "vendor" COLLATE "numerickn"
```

However, it gives the following error, though I see collation exists in DB.

> Error: Query failed: collation "numerickn" for encoding "UTF8" does
> not exist

I am not sure why it does not work if collate exists in the DB. In my vendor name, numeric can appear anywhere within the string, so there is no pattern.

Comment: try with a collation that you know works?

Comment: do you get any error message when you create numerickn?

Comment: simple question is int numerickn or numericn?

Comment: No, we did not get any errors while creating the collation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find why it was not working in the stage environment while in my local it was working.

In the end, I moved away from colation logic and implement the natural sort in a different way found in stack overflow only.

[PostgreSQL ORDER BY issue - natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173558/postgresql-order-by-issue-natural-sort)

I am using Nodejs in my api code. My solution goes as follows

```
qOrderBy = String.raw` ORDER BY  ARRAY(
        SELECT ROW(
            CAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(match[1], ''), '9223372036854775807') AS BIGINT),
            match[2]
          )
          FROM REGEXP_MATCHES(vendor, '(\d*)|(\D*)', 'g')
          AS match ) ${sortOrder}`
  }
```