Ordering query result based on parent child
I am trying to get menu data based on parent child ordering. I was wondering if there was a better way to do what I am trying to achieve.
WITH recursive cte AS
(
--get parent menu
       SELECT 1 as level,
              vchr_menu_name::text,
              vchr_menu_caption,
              pk_bint_menu_id,
              vchr_menu_caption::text AS parent_menu,
              int_order::                text
       FROM   tbl_menu
       WHERE  int_menu_type=0
        and int_show=1
       UNION ALL
--get child menu
       SELECT 
          1+cte.level,
              repeat('.', cte.level * 4) || '--> ' ||mr.vchr_menu_name,
              mr.vchr_menu_caption,
              mr.pk_bint_menu_id,
              cte.parent_menu
                     ||'->'
                     ||mr.vchr_menu_caption,
              cte.int_order::text
                     ||'->'
                     ||mr.int_order::text
       FROM   tbl_menu mr
       JOIN   cte
       ON     mr.bint_parent_id=cte.pk_bint_menu_id
where         int_show=1 and int_menu_type=2
       )
SELECT   *
FROM     cte
ORDER BY naturalsort(int_order) ASC

I am using the natural sort function to maintain the correct ordering. I was wondering if I can achieve the same using only int_order. The maximal level hierarchy is 4.
What I want is something like this:
Parent  1

Child 1
   Grand Child
   Grand Child

Child 2
   Grand Child

Parent 2


Unknown and as is unknowable. The function naturalsort(...) is not a Postgres native function. What is that function of where is its source?

It's a custom function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173558/postgresql-order-by-issue-natural-sort
